# how to decode C stuct like packets - with java socket programming

Tags: java, sockets

new to socket programming in java!.   i am trying my level best to understand java socket programming, and how to decode 'C' strut like packets.

The client is python which sends packet between tags,
 example Payload : `<tag1> data packet 1</tag1><tag2>data packet 2</tag2>`

Have a c code to which received the payload and decode the payload with structure , all the tags are of 30 bytes, data packet 1, 2,.. n will be of different structure

I am fairly new to java program, after searching through the web, i could write a socket server which receives payload from client, now facing problem in decoding the data packets.
I could display the bytes. so Used Arrays.copyOfRange method to get data.

The packet data are something represented as below,

```
typedef struct {

  unsigned char     dataType;
  unsigned char     value[4];

} GEN_VAL

typedef struct {

  unsigned char     dataType;
  unsigned char     numBytes;
  unsigned char     value[32];

} GEN_STR_32;

typedef struct {

    char           startTag[32];
    GEN_STR_32     c_code;
    GEN_STR_32     c_name;
    GEN_STR_32     c_info;

    GEN_VAL        i_type;
    GEN_VAL        i_count1;
    GEN_VAL        i_count2;
    char           endTag[32];

} DATA_PACKET_1;
```

I receive buffer with following code snippet

```
  DataInputStream inStream = new DataInputStream
                        (new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));

 while ( ( noOfBytes = (int)inStream.read(recvBuff)) != -1)
{
 cDecode mydecode = new cDecode();
 mydecode.decodePacket(noOfBytes, recvBuff);
}
```

cDecode.java

```
public void decodePacket(int TotalBytes, byte[] BuffRecv) 
{
    byte[] GetTag = new byte[32];
    byte[] GEN_STR_32 = new byte[32];
    byte[] GEN_INT_4  = new byte[4];

     GetTag = Arrays.copyOfRange(BuffRecv,0,31);
     String TagStr = new String(GetTag).trim();  //get start tag 

     int startloc = 31;
     int offset = startloc + 32;
     GEN_STR_32 = Arrays.copyOfRange(Buff,startloc,offset);
     String cCode = new String(GEN_STR_32).trim();  // get value of cCode
     System.out.println("Code   :" + cCode );

     startloc = offset;
     offset = startloc + 32;
     GEN_STR_32 = Arrays.copyOfRange(Buff,startloc,offset);
     String cName = new String(GEN_STR_32).trim(); //get value of cName
     System.out.println("Name:" + cName );

     startloc = offset;
     offset = startloc + 32;
     GEN_STR_32 = Arrays.copyOfRange(Buff,startloc,offset);
     String cInfo = new String(GEN_STR_32).trim(); //get value of cName
     System.out.println("Info:" + cInfo );

     startloc = offset;
     offset = offset + 4;
     ByteBuffer iTypeByteBuff = ByteBuffer.wrap(GEN_DATA_INT_4);
     int iType= iTypeByteBuff .getInt();
     System.out.println("type :" + iType);

     startloc = offset;
     offset = offset + 4;
     // likewise used ByteBuffer for remaining integer data 
     // for receiving end tag, offset is added with 32!
}
```

first 3 data is string value    and
second 3 data have integer value

String value is displayed correctly.
finding problem in converting byte to integer, not sure whether i am using correct value for startloc and offset  in Arrays.copyOfRange method.

I tried this based on the information i got from net.

I also read about having a separate class without methods for all data structures. but i cant find any complete example, as 'sizeof' is not available in java.

can some one guide me the correct way to decode packets in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think of the data as a stream to be read as a data type, you could extend `DataInputStream` to create a `PacketInputStream` that has a `readDataPacket()` method. Define a `DataPacket` class to hold the data from your C `DATA_PACKET_1` struct.

First the classes to hold your data:

```
public class GenValue {
    private final byte dataType;
    private final byte[] value;

    public GenVal(byte dataType, byte[] value) {
        this.dataType = dataType;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public byte getDataType() {
        return dataType;
    }

    public byte[] getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

public class DataPacket {
    private final String startTag;
    private final String code;
    private final String name;
    private final String info;
    private final GenValue type;
    private final GenValue count1;
    private final GenValue count2;
    private final String endTag;

    public DataPacket(String startTag, other args here...) {
        this.startTag = startTag;
        // Set the other properties from constructor args...
    }

    public String getStartTag() {
        return startTag;
    }

    // Add getters for the other properties...
}
```

And the `DataInputStream` implementation to decode your packets:

```
public class PacketInputStream extends DataInputStream {
    public DataPacket readDataPacket() throws IOException {
        String startTag = readGenStr32();
        String code = readGenStr32();

        // Do the same for name and info...
        ...

        GenValue type = readGenValue();
        GenValue count1 = readGenValue();
        GenValue count2 = readGenValue();

        // Read the endTag the same as the Strings above...
        ...

        return new DataPacket(startTag, code, name, info, type, count1, count2, endTag);
    }

    public String readGenStr32() throws IOException {
        byte[] strBuf = new byte[32];
        readFully(strBuf, 0, 32);
        return new String(strBuf).trim();
    }

    public GenValue readGenValue() throws IOException {
        byte dataType = readByte();
        byte[] value = new byte[4];
        readFully(value);
        return new GenValue(dataType, value);
    }
}
```

Calling code would do something like:

```
PacketInputStream in = new PacketInputStream((new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
DataPacket p = in.readDataPacket();
System.out.println("Start tag: " + p.getStartTag());
System.out.println("Code: " + p.getCode());
// Print other values of interest...
```

I would just override `DataPacket.toString()` and then do `System.out.println(p)`, but there's enough code here already. Also, I would store primitive types instead of using a `GenValue` class, but I don't know enough about your actual data to work that out.

Comment: which package contain PacketInputStream  ? think it is not part of java? any separate library?

Comment: `PackageInputStream` is a class you would create by extending `java.io.DataInputStream` and adding your own `readPacket()` method. Within that method you can call the super class's read methods, like `read(byte[] b)`or `readShort()`.

Comment: Note that `Packet` is just another data type to decode, just like `String` or `short`, only it is composed of the more basic data types already handled by `DataInputStream`.

Comment: thanks Kevin.  finding  confused/ difficult to visualize in object oriented way.. have to try more.

Comment: I've reworked the example code to more closely match your C structure conventions and to be more explicit about the OO.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for your effort, i like to implement and learn! few clarifications to tune my thoughts to yours!
when defined as 'final' for variables , it seems this.variable cant be used? getting error in eclipse.
any significance of using only 'Get' method and not 'Set' method in GenVal class?
in calling code 'readDataPacket' is misspelled for readPacket in PacketInputStream?
is it not the read() (here it is readDataPacket) call should be in loop? think here the readDataPacket is like unpacking the Data? or will this capable of reading entire data in one shot from socket ?

Comment: The `readPacket` was an error. The `final` and lack of getters is called immutability and is for thread safety. Josh Bloch's book _Effective Java_ is a good place to learn about this and many other Java fundamentals.

Comment: As for the loop, yes you would call `readDataPacket` in a loop to read multiple packets from a socket stream. Beware that you must not read data packet bytes from the stream before calling `readDataPacket` and the entire packet's bytes must be available to avoid an `IOException`. See the `DataInputStream` methods `available` , `mark`, and `reset` for help with that. `ByteArrayInputStream` would give you another option. Your example's loop would decode junk data if `noOfBytes` is less than an entire packet, so you'll need to think through that no matter what approach you take.

Comment: Thanks Kevin.  I tried your suggestion and it is working. This has given more insight to object oriented.

Answer (score 1):

For byte arrays or input/output you can use a ByteBuffer.

```
byte[] bytes = ...
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
buf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN); // Intel byte order.
short sh = buf.getShort(sh); // Java short = 2B
int unsignedSh = buf.getShort() & 0xFFFF; // Unsigned short emulation


ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
buf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
buf.putShort(sh); // Java short = 2B
buf.putShort((short) unsignedSh);
```

There also exists a binary format standard **ASN**, to work more grammar like, but in this case the above will do.

One problem on the C side is field alignment and platform portability. One could use macros to transform a struct into a fully specified binary data structure building call.

---

***After comments, using a DataInputStream***

You did not seem to use the data specific read calls for DataInputStream.

```
enum DataType {
    X0,
    GEN_VAL,
    X2,
    X3,
    GEN_STR_32,
    ...
}

class GenStr32 {
     final DataType dataType = DataType.GEN_STR_32;
     int numbytes; // 0..255
     String value; // 32 bytes incl. '\0' in C
}

void readAnyTyped(DataInputStream in) {
    int dataTypeIx = in.readByte() & 0xFF;
    DataType dataType = DataType.values()[dataTypeIx];
    switch (dataType) {
    case GEN_STR_32:
        GenStr32 data = new GenStr32();
        data.numbytes = in.readByte();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[data.numbytes]; // or 32?
        bytes = in.readFully();
        int length = 0;
        while (length < bytes.length && bytes[length] != 0) {
            ++length;
        }
        data.value = new String(bytes, 0, length,
            StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
        process(data);
        break;
    }
}
```

DataInputStream might be more direct. ByteBuffer has the advantage of the specifiable byte order, as java defaults to BIG_ENDIAN.

Comment: Thanks for the info. think this should work for any number of byte array.

Comment: I receive 181 bytes. 5 data are of 32 bytes which has string values, 3 datas of 4 bytes has int values.  so 5*32 = 160 bytes  and 3*4=12 bytes. Out of 181,  i am able to decode 160 bytes of string successfully. In remaining 21 bytes are there,  i think other values like dataType, numBytes  (refer my main question struct def GEN_VAL and GEN_STR_32) are also packed here?!  not sure how to decode this integer value!

Comment: Many formats have what you have, a marker: `dataType` to control what is read. Instead of ByteBuffer you might opt for [**DataInputStream**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html).

Comment: I am using DataInputStream to receive data from socket, kindly see the code snippet given in main question. the packet is received in RecvBuff byte buffer. and ByteBuffer is used only to take integer values. or am i missing something?

Comment: will socket be blocked, If i keep DataInputStream object for processing the data? Have to decode the start tag first and loop to get the data until i reach end tag based on the specific tag. i thought it will be good to receive the data what ever available in socket at that point in time (in a byte buffer, as the binary data is received through socket) and process the data in different thread. But DataInputStream as good methods to take data!

Comment: You may use `available()`  though this will be erratic. That is doable,, buffering, and meanwhile doing something different elsewhere. A Future task would be possible too.

Comment: Thanks Eggen. Your inputs helped me to understand on reading data.