# Java + MySQL : passing Object to Constructor, to store date time in mysql format

Tags: java, mysql

Like to know about following 2 things

1. using Class as type for a variable and return the object to a constructor and set the same.
2. Date and Time string format compatible to MYSQL : best way to store for report generation.

Objective:
   Received Byte buffer has to be decoded and stored in DB. Decoding is based on C structure.

refer earlier post [how to decode C stuct like packets - with java socket programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31317196/how-to-decode-c-stuct-like-packets-with-java-socket-programming)

find the code snippet in reference to the doubt!

GenStr32 Class

```
 public class GenStr32 {

    private byte datatype = 0;
    private byte numbytes = 0;
    private byte[] bValue  = new byte[32];

    public GenDataStr32(byte bDatatype, byte bNumbytes, byte[] bparamVal) {
        this.datatype = bDatatype;
        this.numbytes = bNumbytes;
        this.bValue = bparamVal;
    }

   .... get methods for the variables....

   }// end of GenStr32 Class
```

DateTimeStruct Class

```
  public class DateTimeStruct {

    private byte[] bBufYear = new byte[2];
    private byte   bMonth = 0;
    private byte   bDate = 0;
    private byte   bUnUsed = 0;
    private byte   bHour = 0;;
    private byte   bMin = 0;
    private byte   bSec = 0;
    private byte[] bUnUsedBuff = new byte[7];


    public MeterDateTimeStruct(byte[] bYear, byte bMonth, byte bDate,
            byte bUnUsed, byte bHour, byte bMin, byte bSec, byte[] bUnUsedBuff) {
        super();
        this.bBufYear = bYear;
        this.bMonth = bMonth;
        this.bDate = bDate;
        this.bUnUsed = bUnUsed;
        this.bHour = bHour;
        this.bMin = bMin;
        this.bSec = bSec;
        this.bUnUsedBuff = bUnUsedBuff;
    }

    .... get / set methods ...

  }// end of DateTimeStruct Class
```

PacketOne Class

```
   Public Class PacketOne {

   private String sValueOne;
   private String sValueTwo;
   private DateTimeStruct DateTime;  
   private int iValueOne;
   ....
   ....
   etc

        //PacketOne Constructor 
        public PacketOne(String sValueOne, String sValueTwo, DateTimeStruct DateTime,
                     int iValueOne, .... .... ) {

            this.sValueOne = sValueOne;
            this.sValueTwo = sValueTwo;
            this.DateTime = DateTime;    // how to set this object?! 
            this.iValueOne = iValueOne;

            ..... etc 
        }   

       .... get and set functions ....

   } //end of PacketOne Class
```

DecodePacketOne Class

```
 public class DecodePacketOne {

       byte[] BuffStr32 = new byte[34];
       byte[] Buff4Date = new byte[15];
       byte[] yearbuff  = new byte[2];

       // BuffRecv  contains received buffer

        ...setting StartLoc and Offset ...
        bBuffGenStr32 = Arrays.copyOfRange(BuffRecv,iStartLoc,iOffset);
        GenStr32 Val1Obj = readGenStr32(bBuffGenStr32);  

        // readGenStr32 will read bValue from GenDataStr32 object 
        // and return GenStr32( param1, param2 ...);

        bBuff4Str32 = Val1Obj.getValue();
        String sValue1 = new String(bBuff4Str32).trim();

        /// likewise get sValue2 ..

         ...setting StartLoc and Offset ...
        Buff4Date = Arrays.copyOfRange(BuffRecv,iStartLoc,iOffset);
        DateTimeStruct DateTimeObject = readDateTime(bBuffGenStr32);  

        // readDateTime will read Date values from DateTimeStruct object and 
        // return DateTimeStruct(paramYear, paramMonth, ...)

        yearbuff = DateTimeObject.getYear();   // 
        byte month1 = DateTimeObject.getMonth();



     return new PacketOne ( sValue1, sValue2,DateTimeObject, iValue1 ... other parameters.. )
          // is it right to return an object ?
   }
```

1. Is it possible to return an object like DateTimeObject ? if so how to set that object in PacketOne Constructor.
2. Date and Time information are received as separate bytes. how to convert the byte data to the date format that is compatible to MSQL ? and what is the best way to store Date and Time for report generation based on Date and Time.